# Featured image from custom to Wordpress database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I want to adapt my old custom website database (composed of only one table) to Wordpress database.

All data has been correctly imported in both tables (`wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`) with a php code that I can share if needed.

Here is a screenshot of my `wp_posts` table...[image: wp_posts screenshot]

...and a screenshot of my `wp_postmeta` table (I imported only one entry to facilitate understanding).
[image: wp_postmeta screenshot]

As you can see, `wp_posts/post_parent` column of `id` 2 (referring to the featured image) is well linked to `id` 1 (which is the post).

But in my wordpress admin panel, I still have no linked featured image.[image: blank featured image]

**Is there another place where the image and the post have to be linked?**

Answer (score 1):

To display data (images) from another database, you can:

1. create a child theme
2. in the child theme, create custom templates for pages/lists where the external data (images) will be displayed
3. in the functions.php of the child theme, write a function that interpolates the id's of the wp_postmeta to the external database
4. with this interpolation, return the image link desired and provide it to the template as a variable
5. with the variable of the image link, display your related data (image)